# Access VBA rename a file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I trying to use two textboxes to perform a rename in VBA access.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command61_Click() 
    Name Me.sourFullPath As Me.destFullPath 
End Sub
```

Both `sourFullPath` and `destFullPath` have the whole file path include the folder path and the file name + extension, they all on the same drive.
But after I ran it, Access gives me

> Run-time error 5: invalid procedure call or argument.

Does anyone know what causes that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is correct so check what you actually are trying to do:

```
Private Sub Command61_Click() 
    Debug.Print "Source: '" & Me.sourFullPath & "' Target: '" & Me.destFullPath & "'"
    Name Me.sourFullPath As Me.destFullPath 
End Sub
```

Also, the target folder must exist.

Comment: Make sure that the file isn't open as well.

Comment: If the file was open it would give a different error "Run-time error '75': Path/File access error" so that isn't the issue in the question above. Also if the path was wrong it would give an error "Run-time error '53': File not found"

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the error code it says on

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445484(v=vs.60).aspx

•An argument probably exceeds the range of permitted values.

If you extend the destination to over 255 characters then it does fail but with an error

> Run-time error '53': File not found

It still could be that your source or destination path is to long.