# How to convert a file before importing to Access Table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi my dear developer friends,

I have ".XLS" files which are basically ".TXT". In short, the file is with the wrong extension. I want to import it in access table. So how do I convert these files before importing to access using VBA? I googled a lot, but didn't get anything!

I am trying to import files using the code

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, False, "B1:AV10"
```

But, after running the code, I get a runtime error : "External table is not in the expected format"
I believe this error is because the extension of file is different than the format. But, if I open this file in excel and then save it as ".XLSX" and import, then it works. But, I want to programmatically convert these files before importing to access table. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Best Regards

Comment: If they really are TXT files, you can rename them, and then use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext

Comment: Are the files txt files, If so, rename them, if not, convert them. It's not clear the situation. To check if they are txt, right click them in windows explorer and open them with notepad.

Comment: Options are to rename or open and save to xlsx format. Either can be accomplished via code.

Comment: For others who may find this perplexing, over the years I have encountered several web applications with a "Download Excel file" feature that downloads a CSV (text) file with a `.xls` extension. That would "fool" older versions of Excel into opening them via double-clicking the file so the user wouldn't have to launch Excel and then do File > Open. Newer versions of Excel are not that gullible, but then Excel now associates itself with .csv files anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using VBA to open a tab delimited .txt file to save to .xlsx format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616886/using-vba-to-open-a-tab-delimited-txt-file-to-save-to-xlsx-format) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935920/access-vba-rename-a-file

Comment: Renaming the file didn't work. But, I wrote a code in access to open the file in excel and save it as .XLSX and then import this file to Access table. Thank you everyone for your help and tips! Best Regards